# mysql inner join get only the last 3 equals

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-normalization

I Hope someone could help me.

My Query.

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_device` 
INNER JOIN `tbl_temperature` ON tbl_device.ID = tbl_temperature.DevID
```

Result.

[image: Query Results]

How can get something like this as shown in the photo on the link.

[image: tbl_device.DevID]

I need to get only the last 3 result of the tbl_device.DevID

I apologize for my bad english, it's really hard to explain. Any help is realy much appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to simulate row_number in MySQL and filter on that row_number.

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text.

Comment: 1. The problem is not bad English but not making the effort to say what you mean. You don't even clearly explain what example output you want. 2. What does this have to do with normalization?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use ANSI-standard window functions (`row_number()` in particular).  But MySQL does not support those (yet).

In MySQL, probably the best way is to use variables:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM tbl_device d JOIN
     (SELECT t.*,
             (@rn := if(@d = t.devid, @rn + 1,
                        if(@d := t.devid, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      FROM (SELECT t.*
            FROM tbl_temperature t
            ORDER BY DevID, id DESC
           ) t CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @d := -1, @rn := 0) params
     ) t
     ON tbl_device.ID = tbl_temperature.DevID
WHERE rn <= 3;
```

EDIT:

Here is a simpler way to express the logic.  It might be performant with the right indexes:

```
SELECT d.*, t.*
FROM tbl_device d INNER JOIN
     tbl_temperature t
     ON d.ID = t.DevID
WHERE t.ID >= (SELECT t2.ID
               FROM tbl_temperature t2
               WHERE t2.DevId = t.DevId
               ORDER BY t2.ID DESC
               OFFSET 2 LIMIT 1
              );
```

For performance, this can use an index on `tbl_temperature(devid, id)`.

Comment: i believe the WHERE should be more like `WHERE rn >= 2 AND rn <= 3` then it will fetch from the second record.

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . The OP appears to want the three most recent temperatures for each device.  Hence, `where rn <= 3`.

Comment: indeed ive interpreted the topicstaters image wrong.. it did look like he wanted to select a range from the second record

Comment: Hi Gordon, thank you very much for your help, it works!

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_device` 
INNER JOIN `tbl_temperature` ON tbl_device.ID = tbl_temperature.DevID
ORDER BY tbl_temperature.DevID DESC
LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0
```

The order column can be not the same as in my example. Google MySQL LIMIT OFFSET

Or if you need to get only three last results from one of your tables then join it to another then it will be something like

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_device INNER JOIN
(SELECT .... FROM other_table ORDER BY your_column DESC LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0) as 
T1 ON T1.id = tbl_device.ID
```

Comment: won't work..this selects the last orderd 3 records from the table.

Comment: I updated my answer. Is that what you're looking for? If not, describe what's wrong.

Comment: hi  Восилей, thanks for your response, I'am currently checking on it...

Comment: just tried your query                                                                  
SELECT * FROM tbl_device INNER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM tbl_temperature ORDER BY DevID DESC LIMIT 3 OFFSET 0) as 
T1 ON T1.id = tbl_device.ID - it shows no results, please let me know if i missed somethings...thanks!

Comment: @ArizSumagui your question is not detailed. can u explain in some detail.? what you want? sum of temp_reading?